# Download file from FTP server directly to browser with PHP

Tags: php, ftp

`ftp_get()` downloads a file from an FTP server and saves the file to local server.

So when I want to download a file from an FTP server to my browser, the file will first be downloaded to the local server and then downloaded to the browser.

This causes double bandwidth. Is there a way to download a file from an FTP to browser directly?

Answer (score 2):

`ftp_get()` or `curl` or any PHP script will require opening a stream to the source, and passing it the client browser. You still use 2 streams, resulting in double the bandwidth usage. The only way to avoid this is to link to or have the end-user collect the file directly.

I am assuming that you're collecting the file from a private FTP location, passing the credentials, and you do not want the end-user to have these or they do not know them. Yet for them, it should be a seamless download.

Not a lot of good ways to do this. In my mind, making an FTP Client connection via Flash in the end-users browser is one way. You could dynamically create flash or have the flash collect the credentials (encrypted), and then perform the connection to the FTP Server from the end-users browser (after decrypting the credentials) and download the file directly to the end-user.

Comment: my site located in the server 1 and some file located in the server 2.there is no solution to download file from server 2 to client directly?

Comment: Not via PHP. Since PHP is scripting the server1, the request would come from the server1. If you want the user to download something from server2, the user needs to connect to server2.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is to redirect the client browser to the `ftp://` URL. That's doable when the FTP site allows an anonymous read access. Most (all) web browsers support FTP natively.

Depending on a workflow, you either redirect from the PHP code:

```
header("Location: ftp://download.example.com/file.pdf");
```

On you directly use `ftp://` URL in the HTML code:

```html
<a href="ftp://download.example.com/file.pdf">Download</a>
```

If anonymous read access is not allowed, you'd have to include the credentials in the URL, what you probably do not want to.

```
ftp://username:password@download.example.com/file.pdf
```