# download file from other server to client directly php

Tags: php, curl, ftp

my site located in server 1 and some file located in server 2. When i want to download file from server 2 to client by using `ftp_get()` or `curl()` , that function download file from server 2 to server 1 not to client. 
Server 2 is a private ftp server. If that is not possible with ftp there is no solution other than ftp ? 
what is the best solution to store file to server 2?

Comment: You can redirect them to the FTP URL.

Comment: Maybe this will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php

Comment: server 2 require username and password.so how i can include username and password?

Comment: Why are you posting the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034047/download-file-from-ftp-server-directory-to-browser-with-php/30045249#30045249

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use Cross Domain enabled ajax to send file (post method) to another server and use below header on server 2 to accept post data from server 1.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://server1.com');
```